# ¿Cómo añadir un título a un dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colab

Empezando a hacer cosillas en python me surge la siguiente duda.
Estoy trabajando con un dataframe (panda) en python y me lee la primera fila como el título, pero no consigo que no me lo haga...Alguien me puede ayudar a ponerle un título a la columna sin borrar el primer elemento.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Proporciona tu código para partir de una base y no tener que crear un código desde cero. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) o mirar [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la pregunta. Puedes editar la pregunta en el botón de "Editar".

Comment: Bienvenid@ Aris, aporta más información a tu pregunta por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Si describes un error sin mostrar el código, esto se convierte en un juego de adivinanzas, lo cual nos perjudica en la busqueda de una solución.

Answer (score 1):

si estas trabajando con CSV podrías utilizar el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('ruta_de_tu_archivo.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: Hola, tal vez el OP no esta usando un CSV, primero podrías preguntarle para aclarar y luego agregar una respuesta, ya que esta podría no ser valida, saludos.